# vector of string, each strings length and strlen in c++

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a vector of strings. I need to find the length of each string. Then I assume that when i convert each string to char array and do a `strlen` on the char array , the values should match.
Better explanation: Here is the code

```
VerifyX509CertChain(
    const std::vector<std::string> & cert_chain,
    const std::string& hostname,
    const std::string& auth_type)
{

    const unsigned char* buf;
    const char* str;
    int vec_size = cert_chain.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < vec_size; i++)
    {

        str = cert_chain[i].c_str();
        MY_LOGV(StringPrintf("VerifyX509CertChain,string size  %s %s", str, cert_chain[i].c_str()).c_str());
        int string_size = cert_chain[i].size();
        int string_len = cert_chain[i].length();
        MY_LOGV(StringPrintf("VerifyX509CertChain,string size  %d %d", string_size, string_len).c_str());
        int string_size1 = strlen(str);
        int string_size2 = strlen(cert_chain[i].c_str());
        MY_LOGV(StringPrintf("VerifyX509CertChain,char size  %d %d", string_size1, string_size2).c_str());
    }
}
```

Results which I get are:

> V/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport( 1544): VerifyX509CertChain,string size  1326 1326
>
> V/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport( 1544): VerifyX509CertChain,char size  32 32
>
> V/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport( 1544): in SSL_CTX_use_certificate1
>
> V/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport( 1544): VerifyX509CertChain,string size  985 985
>
> V/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport( 1544): VerifyX509CertChain,char size  32 32
>
> V/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport( 1544): in SSL_CTX_add_extra_chain_cert1
>
> V/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport( 1544): VerifyX509CertChain,string size  897 897
>
> V/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport( 1544): VerifyX509CertChain,char size  32 32

I find it a strange behviour as `cert_chain[i].size()` return 1326,985 and 897 but `strlen(str)` or `strlen(cert_chain[i].c_str())` always return 32.
I expected both the values to be the same, i mean between `cert_chain[i].size` and `strlen(str)` but they are different. Why is this so??
Please clarify this doubt. Thanks in advance

Comment: your code does not match your output, please fix

Comment: If you are using the std::string type, don't use strlen().   It's that simple.  If you can avoid using strlen() when you are not using the std::string type, so much the better.

Answer (score 7):

C++ string can contain any bytes, including NULL values (`"\0"`), which are treated as endline character by strlen.

Example:

```
std::string s("\0",5); // std::string ss("a",3) gives "aaa"
std::cout << s.size() << " " << strlen(s.c_str()) << std::endl;
```

Output:
`5 0`